# Единственное или множественное число? Какой из вариантов верный?

Tags: выбор-слов, единственное-множественное-число

> Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на рожденного
>   (усыновленного) после 1 января 2020 года третьего ребенка или
>   последующих детей.

ИЛИ

> Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на рожденных
>   (усыновленных) после 1 января 2020 года третьего ребенка или
>   последующих детей.

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу здесь проблемы, решаемой **правилами § 194 справочника Розенталя** http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-194-dva-opredeleniya-pri-odnom-sushchestvitelnom .  **§** называется "**Два определения при одном существительном**". В Вашем примере ***Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на рожденного (усыновленного) после 1 января 2020 года третьего ребенка или последующих детей*** у каждого существительного своё определение: третьего ребёнка, последующих детей.

Сложность здесь в том, что есть ещё одно необособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом ***рожденного (усыновленного) после 1 января 2020 года***, оно согласуется с близлежащим сочетанием  **третьего ребенка**, а перед следующим за ним сочетанием **последующих детей** пропускается, чтобы не было повтора, ведь должно было бы быть так: *Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на рожденного (усыновленного) после 1 января 2020 года третьего ребенка или на рожденных (усыновленных) после 1 января 2020 года последующих детей*.

Во множественном числе причастие **рождённых** было бы в следующем случае: *Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на **рожденных (усыновленных**) после 1 января 2020 года третьего  или последующих **детей**.* Здесь было бы согласование по смыслу - указание на то, что детей много, но было бы возможно и согласование в единственном числе **по соседству с порядковым числительным третьего**:  *Получение единовременной выплаты в размере 20 000 рублей на **рожденного (усыновленного**) после 1 января 2020 года **третьего**  или последующих детей.*